# Creating a wrapper library for LGPL code and distribute the used LGPL code as its own library?

Tags: lgpl

I've been working on a proof of concept prototype for my company. The libraries for the board I've been using are licensed under the LGPL. We've been happy enough that we're now considering using this hardware in production.

I understand the LGPL does not require me to release all of my application's source code. However anyone must be free to modify and compile against whatever LGPL licensed code I am using.

To remain compliant, can I simply create a wrapper library for the LGPL code, call the LGPL code from my portion with the wrapper, and distribute the used LGPL code as its own library? And possibly provide headers that would allow you to modify the LGPL portion and recompile?